# LTspice XVII problem simulating SEPIC converter

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, ltspice, sepic

This is the second time I'm trying to simulate a SEPIC converter today. First I went with [LT3959](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/3959fa.pdf), but after hours of trying to make it work, I assumed there is something wrong with the component and it would be easier to choose another component and everything would work.

The second time i went with [LT8364](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/8364f.pdf) and again I did everything as the datasheet said, placed realistic components (parasitic C,L,R) but again I can't make it to work.

I'm using the newest version of LTspice. (LTspice XVII (x64), May 4 2018

**The problem that occurs is that the output voltage is 0V.**

[image]

This is my schematic:

[image]

Vin and Vout:

[image]

Can anyone help me? Should I instal older version of LTspice?

*.asc file: [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1SxleEaWlSjyyVKHol32b03OllJxvW7Hk)

Comment: If you make the .asc file available somewhere people that want to test it themselves have an easier time.

Comment: Why did you couple L1 and L2 to form a transformer?

Comment: Because it reduces the output ripple, you can do it without coupleing, it will work fine, just bigger ripple

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set the parallel resistance on the inductors to have the same value as the series resistance, which effectively fully dampens them (more like turning them into slightly inductive resistors). The parallel resistance should be at least k\$\Omega\$ in value, if not tens or more. If you remove those values, everything works.

Also, the parallel cap at the input does exactly nothing, unless you set `Rser` to the source, or cap, but then you can simply specify the source to be `7 Rser=10m Cpar=4.7u`, and delete the cap.

Comment: Sir, you are a lifesaver! If you ever pass throu Slovenia or Croatia, you're getting a beer from me!

Comment: @Lazyboy Well, I'll certainly remember *that*. :-)